# cant make an error statement to dm users discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I tried putting a catch error if the user didn't get the message but for some reason, I get an error

```
    client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const linkId = pool.createLink(member.id);
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('reCAPTCHA Verification')
        .setDescription(`To gain access to this server you must solve a captcha. The link will expire in 15 minutes.\nhttp://${domain == '' ? 'localhost:8050' : domain}/verify/${linkId}`)
        .setColor('YELLOW');
    member.send(embed)

} catch (e) {
    console.log(`Error adding role to user ${discordId}.`)
}
```

get an error missing ","
added "," `}, catch (e) {`
and then I get Argument expression expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Problem**

The error is probably because your code is not formatted properly at all? You have a function `member => {}` and then you have a `catch` immediately following the function, and you never even close your `client.on()` parentheses.

Your program properly understanding entirely incorrect syntax is as infeasible as speaking gibberish to someone who speaks a different language and expecting them to understand you. When learning a new language, you need to be aware of new grammar rules, vocabulary, and more that may differ immensely from your own primary language. This is true of programming languages as well; javascript is very flexible, but your program will not be able to decipher immensely inaccurate syntax (which is the equivalent of gibberish to the program).

Please try to learn more about `try/catch` statements, javascript functions, syntax errors, and proper syntax. This is an immensely simple formatting issue, and questions like this one really should not be present on StackOverflow. Looking at some basic javascript tutorials, doing some quick research (perhaps even looking at some bot examples), and/or doing *a single Google search* could have solved your problem within seconds.

**The Solution**

This is the proper, more accurate syntax:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const linkId = pool.createLink(member.id);
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('reCAPTCHA Verification')
    .setDescription(`To gain access to this server you must solve a captcha. The link will expire in 15 minutes.\nhttp://${domain == '' ? 'localhost:8050' : domain}/verify/${linkId}`)
    .setColor('YELLOW');
    member.send(embed).catch(() => {console.log("Couldn't send message.")});
});
```

This is, of course, assuming that the formatting was the actual issue and you didn't just format it poorly when adding the code to your question. If it was only poorly formatted in your question and properly formatted in your actual code, then the issue isn't even present in the code you provided (in which case your question cannot even be answered, unless you provide the proper code).

Comment: still gets error when users block dms from server

Comment: This answer's catch statement should catch the error, when users have blocked DMs.

Answer (score 0):

i am getting an error

```
 DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\GRPIL-BOT\src\DiscordVerification-master\DiscordVerification-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\GRPIL-BOT\src\DiscordVerification-master\DiscordVerification-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/790342794140975115/messages',
  code: 50007,
  httpStatus: 403
}
```

which

```
try {
        const linkId = pool.createLink(member.id);
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('reCAPTCHA Verification')
        .setDescription(`To gain access to this server you must solve a captcha. The link will expire in 15 minutes.\nhttp://${domain == '' ? 'localhost:8050' : domain}/verify/${linkId}`)
        .setColor('YELLOW');
        member.send(embed)

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Error adding role to user ${discordId}.`)
    }
```

should avoid the error

Comment: This is not the answer. Not the answer, update your question.